# Comment on "Mini-Answers" -- To whom was this directed?

Tags: discussion

Very recently, I noticed that a new contributor asked a seemingly sincere, innocuous question. That OP was closed, and I understand why it was:

***What verses can I use to prove the Trinity? [closed]*** — cj564 131, 4

Fair enough.

**The comment chain then proceeded as follows**:

> Hello, this question is off-topic here, but has been asked and answered at christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/… – **curiousdannii**

> @cj564 There's an interesting article you might wish to read on the subject titled "The Biblical Doctrine of the Godhead" here. It should help you defend the Godhead in your future discussions. – **Xeno**

> Seriously, stop putting mini answers in the comments here. If you want to post defences of non-Trinitarian theologies, go do so at the Christianity site. It is not only a misuse of comments, it's off-topic on this site! – **curiousdannii**

I should hasten to add there was another post by separate contributor that was apparently soon deleted (I don't know when relative to my own). Come to think of it, the post was definitely non-trinitarian...

**Was this last comment directed to me?** Maybe I have this all mixed up? Since I knew I couldn't respond to this new user's request, I thought — for his/her sake — that I might simply point them in what I felt was an appropriate direction for assistance.

Are comments like mine frowned upon on BH-SE? I really had no idea, so apologies if that is the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Two other people were posting anti-Trinitarian arguments. It doesn't matter who they were. I deleted them because it's not what the OP was looking for.